# Table of content not referring unicode characters

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I have the following title:

```
##A Title with icon &#x270F;
```

I want to reference it in a table of contents but the following does not work:

```
- [A Title with icon &#x270F;](#a-title-with-icon-&#x270f;)
```

It is also fine to remove the icon in the summary, but how to accomplish the linking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To link the following title (pay attention to space after hashes):

```
## A Title with icon &#x270F;
```

just ignore the Unicode character (pay attention to the trailing hyphen):

```
- [A Title with icon &#x270F;](#a-title-with-icon-)
```

P.S: tested on GitHub and BitBucket, it works fine.